# What's going under the hood in this simple C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{ 
    int a = 5;
    a = (a = 10, a++, a--);
    std::cout << a;

}
```

Output is 11,
   But when I modify the line

```
a = a=10,a++,a--;
```

Output is 10
What effect does removing the ( ) operator has and in what order the operators are being executed.

Comment: Comma has [lowest precedence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444099/1708801)

Comment: @Rohit use compiler warnings `-Wall`

Comment: Wait, what? undefined behavior? The comma operator introduces a sequence point @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: _What effect does removing the ( ) operator has and in what order the operators are being executed_ Better question: why are you so uninterested in learning these details that you would rather ask random people for help? Write some code and figure the answer out yourself. For self-bonus points, inspect the assembly code the compiler can generate (if you ask it to) and spend some time to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The + and - operators take precedence before the assignment operator and the +,- signs are read by the compiler from left to right, whereas the assignment operators are read by the compiler from right to left. So:
    1) a++
    2) a--
    3) a=10
    4) a =

Answer (score 0):

The c++ compiler will pass your complete set code to a binary tree which will rearrange your code according to the precedence of the operator = + - etc in left node or right node